# I get an error parsing value to left in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, html, for-loop

This code is suppose to iterate 3 million times to the left and when it get's to 3 million go back to the first array position, but I can't do it somehow. Can someone help me make it work if it's possible without an set timer?

Body:

```
<div id="placeDiv">ok</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var times = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3000000; i++) {
    times.push(i);
}
var move=times;             
if(i == move.length-1) {
    i=0;
} else {
    i=i+1;
}
document.getElementById("placeDiv").style.left = move[i];
</script>
```

Css:

```
<style type="text/css">
#placeDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: purple;
}
</style>
```

Comment: First of all 30000 isn't 3 million !

Comment: _“if it's possible without an set timer”_ – without using a timer, you won’t get any kind of _animation_ (assuming that’s what you’re after?). And of course setting a value for `left` without a _unit_ is wrong (unless that value is `0`).

Comment: but for background color of a css div, it's a different, is there a difference between document.getElementById("left").style.left=array[i] and document.getElementById("bgcolor").style.backgroundColor=array[i]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

```
<div id="ok">ok</div>
```

javascript:

```
for (var i=0; i<700000; i++) {
    document.getElementById("ok").style.left = (i) + "px";
    if(i==500) alert(i);
}
```

css:

```css
#ok { position: absolute; }
```

Finally I understand the unit concept of css style left.